# How to use HSQLDB as a datasource in Websphere Application Server?

Tags: jdbc, websphere, hsqldb

I try to set up a local development infrastructure and I want to use [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/) as a datasource with my **WAS 6.1**. I already know that I have to use [Apache DBCP](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp) to get a connection pooling, but I'm stuck when my application tries to get the first connection.

**What I've done**

In WAS I created a JDBC provider with the class `org.apache.commons.dbcp.cpdsadapter.DriverAdapterCPDS` and removed everything from the classpath input field. Then I put *commons-dbcp.jar*, *commons-pool.jar* and *hsqldb.jar* in  `MYAPPSERVERDIRECTORY/lib/ext`.

Then I created a new datasource with that provider. I added the following custom properties:

- `driver=org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver`
- `url=jdbc:hsqldb:file:///C:/mydatabase.db;shutdown=true`
- `user=SA`
- `password=`

**My Problem**

When I run my application and the first connection to the database is made, I get the following exception:

```
---- Begin backtrace for Nested Throwables
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driverDSRA0010E: SQL-Status = 08001, Fehlercode = 0
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:592)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:196)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.cpdsadapter.DriverAdapterCPDS.getPooledConnection(DriverAdapterCPDS.java:205)
at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.InternalGenericDataStoreHelper$1.run(InternalGenericDataStoreHelper.java:918)
at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.InternalGenericDataStoreHelper.getPooledConnection(InternalGenericDataStoreHelper.java:955)
at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.WSRdbDataSource.getPooledConnection(WSRdbDataSource.java:1437)
at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.WSManagedConnectionFactoryImpl.createManagedConnection(WSManagedConnectionFactoryImpl.java:1089)
at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.FreePool.createManagedConnectionWithMCWrapper(FreePool.java:1837)
at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.FreePool.createOrWaitForConnection(FreePool.java:1568)
at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.PoolManager.reserve(PoolManager.java:2338)
at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.ConnectionManager.allocateMCWrapper(ConnectionManager.java:909)
at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.ConnectionManager.allocateConnection(ConnectionManager.java:599)
at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcDataSource.getConnection(WSJdbcDataSource.java:439)
at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcDataSource.getConnection(WSJdbcDataSource.java:408)
```

Any tips on this? I suspect I'm using a wrong class from hsqldb, or maybe my JDBC url is wrong...

Answer (score 2):

In the example given in BDCP docs, the `org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver` class is used as the driver. The `org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver` is supported only in HSQLDB 2.x, but the other class is supported by all versions of HSQLDB.

Comment: Ah, ok. I'm using hsqldb 2.0 for my tests.

Comment: And it is likely BDCP does not know about the new class name, so you need to use the old class name.